# C++: Design data structure(s) to store multi-keyed object set to be able to collect and traverse a hyper-planes of that set

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a storage for a large series (hundreds of millions) of results of alike scientific experiments. An experiment has many discrete-valued attributes (like lattice point of emitter, lattice point of receiver, time of emission event, temperature and elevation at the emission and at the receiver etc) and experiment results (like emission strength, received strength etc). The data is input as a huge input flow.

I'd like to design a storage structure that would allow organization of the input data in several discrete dimensions (representing attributes). I'd like also to be able to obtain all the experiments' results related to a certain attribute value (like, "all experiments from lattice point #10" or "all experiments where emission was received at elevation level 100m". Such a selection should form an array that would allow some en-mass processing (like averaging the results over the set of such a selection).

What could be the proper C++ data structures (preferably made of STL) that allow for such fast searches and combinations?

I've heard that the thing I want is somehow related to [Filter (high-order function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29), but I'm not good at functional programming.

Comment: Ummm... Why not use some embedded DB like SQLite? It does all that you need, quite literarly. It would not be even a big overkill. If you would be going to implement such system by yourself, you would end up quite close to the functionality. A well developed DB system is written optimally for both memory and time constraints, which I believe would be most difficult if you tried to implement everything by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe seems like a typical usecase for a database. In case there is a reasons why you don't want to use a database or want a c++ only solution maybe you can get some ideas from how popular DB-s are implemented. For instance some relational databases use B+ trees.